# What happens to the energy of a capacitor after a dielectric is inserted?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

Consider a parallel plate capacitor having capacitance $ C$ and charge $Q$. In this case, the capacitor's energy is $\frac{Q^2}{2C}$. Now, if a dielectric is inserted, $C$ increases, and thus its energy decreases.

My question is - where does the energy go? If it gets used up to polarise the dielectric, then if we remove the dielectric, how does it regain the energy from the dielectric?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is - where does the energy go?

Someone has to insert or remove the dielectric and that will require work (either positive or negative depending on the situation). Work is where the energy goes.

Comment: More specifically, the person who inserts the dielectric will have to stop it from oscillating (it is sucked in and will hence overshoot). Inserting it does not require work, removing it does (your sign is wrong). Otherwise this is a perfect answer.

Comment: I think that inserting can also require work on the inserters behalf... if what is already in there is more dielectric that what is being inserted. E.g., an oil-filled capacitor gap into which foam is inserted... besides work can be positive or negative.

Comment: Of course, yes. Unless you read the question to imply that there must not have been a dielectricum inside the capacitor yet, as I did.